# All to All broadcasting implementation and MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing, message-passing

I am learning MPI and currently trying to implement a all to all broadcasting using send and receive operations. I know that number of processors is going to be the power of 2 and I wanted to implement an effective solution for this problem. I structured my thoughts like following.

[all to all in a balanced binary tree with 8 processors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xax5r.png)

First, the red copy and exchange operations are done. Then the green operations should be completed and finally, the purple operations would conclude the all to all message sharing.

Assuming:

- Processor 0 has the message A
- Processor 1 has the message B
- Processor 2 has the message C
- Processor 3 has the message D
- Processor 4 has the message E
- Processor 5 has the message F
- Processor 6 has the message G
- Processor 7 has the message H

Some of the steps:

1. Processor 0 shares its message with Processor 7 and vice versa. So they both have messages A and H.
2. Processor 1 shares its message with Processor 6 and vice versa. So they both have messages B and G.
3. Processor 2 shares its message with Processor 5 and vice versa. So they both have messages C and F.
4. Processor 3 shares its message with Processor 4 and vice versa. So they both have messages D and E.  **(The red operations are done at this step.)**
5. Processor 0 shares its message with Processor 3 and vice versa. So they both have messages A  H D and E.
6. Processor 1 shares its message with Processor 2 and vice versa. So they both have messages B G C and F

...

I could not write a satisfying code for finding out the pair given the rank of the current processor. I thought finding out all the possible pairs recursively at the beginning like a look-up table to be used. But I would like to ask if there is a better way I could continue with? Also is the approach correct?

Comment: What about something like `for (step=0; ...; step++) { peer = rank ^ (1<<step); ...`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I looked into a hypercube organization for the same problem. And the pair calculation was similar. Thanks for your comment I think this solves my problem.

Comment: MPI's own MPI_Alltoall collective routine should already by highly-optimised so you should compare the performance of your own point-to-point implementation to this routine.

Comment: @DavidHenty I completed the implementation and compared my results to built in version as you suggested. I can see that my implementation which uses a hypercube approach is around 2x faster than the built-in version. I was curios about the reason. Since MPI_Alltoall routine does not assume the number of processors to be power of 2, I suspect they cannot use the hypercube approach. Is that the case? I could not find implementation details for the routine. Do you have any idea about the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both based on the comment of the [Gilles Gouaillardet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062491/gilles-gouaillardet) and other research I have conducted on this problem, I solved my problem and wanted to share the methodology I used in doing so.

First of all, before implementing an All-to-all broadcasting, I highly suggest you to take a look at this [page](http://users.atw.hu/parallelcomp/ch04lev1sec2.html). Since for my problem I knew the number of processors would be power of 2, I implemented the algorithm using hypercube approach.

```
procedure ALL_TO_ALL_BC_HCUBE(my_id, my_msg, d, result) 
begin 
   result := my_msg; 
   for i := 0 to d - 1 do 
       partner := my id XOR 2i; 
       send result to partner; 
       receive msg from partner; 
       result := result U msg; //U for union
   endfor; 
end ALL_TO_ALL_BC_HCUBE
```

*the algorithm is taken from the mentioned page*

I compared my results with the built-in MPI_Alltoall routine. The runtime for my implementation seems to be working around 1.5x-2x faster than the built-in version.